# MS Office online (WOPI) Integration into Servicenow

Tags: integration, servicenow

I am not sure whether the WOPI host can be placed on the ServiceNow and not sure whether the WOPI client can also be implemented inside the ServiceNow. I need some help in the architecting solution for integrating the WOPI into ServiceNow. Anyone has done this before please let me know the answers to the above queries, please. Thanks

Comment: I solved this in a different way. I used ServiceNow APIs directly in MS Word so that I can now checkout what file I want to and then make changes and check-in directly into servicenow

Answer (score 1):

I solved this in a different way. I used ServiceNow APIs directly in MS Word so that I can now checkout what file I want to and then make changes and check-in directly into servicenow

Comment: Can you please tell me how you implemented that? (Step by step guide will be very helpful)